# Ajustar CSS na página independente de navegador

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net

Tenho uma função em uma página (asp.net) que chama outra como um popUP:

BtnFinalizar.OnClientClick = "javascript:ExibirPopupMobile('/ShoppingCart/Formulario.aspx', 900,580); return false;";

Usando o Chrome está vindo correto, centralizado na página, mais se usar o Firefox está diferente, está sendo aplicada a uma div que controla tudo ID=”colorbox”

Como eu poderia setar um valor padrão independente de navegador

```
element.style {
    display: block;
    visibility: visible;
    top: 42px;
    left: 502px;
    position: fixed;
    width: 900px;
    height: 580px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

se tudo que deseja é centralizar o elemento na pagina, então um valor em `px` para o `top` e o `left` não é a melhor opção.

então tente usar o seguinte `css`: `top: 50%; left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%);`

```css
.centro {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

html, body {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.bloco {
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px black;
  width: 240px;
  height: 180px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="bloco centro">
</div>
```

Comment: Amigo, muito agradecido por sua contribuição!